# Open hyperlink in excel/powerpoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

So I have a list that will be created in column F (could be 1 could be 20) of hyperlinks that will open Power point files.  My goal is to create a VBA macro that will open these hyperlinks (=hyperlink) that are referencing specific file destinations that are power points files, copy all slides in each power point and combine all of them to make one power point.  Will probably have to start with a blank power point in the formula then open subsequent links - copy slides - paste slides - close link - open next link (loop).

This is a lot I know - but this is something that would be very helpful for my Church project.

Comment: StackOverflow members will help you debug code you've written but it's not a code-writing service. You're expected to do some research, write some code yourself, then if it doesn't work, post it here with a description of what it's supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: If i could have found something online or through research i wouldn't be posting anything here, everything i've seen refers to something like below that doesn't deal with opening file destinations and combining them...and if they do, its only regarding excel files not power point:                                                                                                                       Sub sbLoopThroughAllLinksinSheet()
'For each link in the worksheet
For Each lnk In Sheets("Sheet1").Hyperlinks
    'display link address
    MsgBox lnk.Address
Next
End Sub

Comment: The key to getting started is creating a better search term. I always start with _powerpoint vba_, which right away narrows down the results. If I get too many non-vba answers, I'll use _powerpoint "vba"_ The quotes mean Google _must_ find the term _VBA_ on the page. If I get too many Excel results, I'll add _-excel_, which removes all Excel results. These days, one key to being a good programmer is being very savvy with internet searches.

Comment: Have a look here. It describes how to use the .Slide.InsertFromFile method of your activepresentation object.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.insertfromfile?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbapp10.chm530006);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue